# How can I check if a user is connected from a view, using the Secure module

Tags: security, view, module, playframework

I'm using the Secure module if that wasn't clear from my title:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/secure

(The Security controller resides in the (standard) controllers package)

I have this in my main.html template:

```
#{if Security.isConnected != true}
    <a href="#" id="loginSlider">Login</a>
#{/if}
#{else}
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
#{/else}
```

And it doesn't seem to work as "Security" is null from here.
I've found it to be fairly poorly documented on playframework.org.

[EDIT]
Things I've tried:
Adding a @ in front of the Controller: #{if @Security.isConnected != true}
Prefixing with package name: #{if @controllers.Security.isConnected != true}

I've verified that I am indeed logged in by navigating to a secure page.

[EDIT2]
Found a workaround that works, but I dislike it.
Basically, the Security controller method isConnected does this: return session.contains("username").
So I can do that check in my view:

`#{ifnot session.contains("username")}`

But its not the optimal solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#{ifnot controllers.Security.isConnected()}
    <a href="#" id="loginSlider">Login</a>
#{/ifnot}
#{else}
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
#{/else}
```